# Many icons don't show up in gucharmap on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, icons, bugs

I just installed gucharmap this package on my Ubuntu system but don't know why many icons can't show up.[image: just like this]

Does anyone koow the reason? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `gucharmap` will only show characters for which it has a font that displays them.  Most fonts have a fallback character that includes the character values in a box, which is what you're seeing here.

If you want to see the characters for a particular script, you need to install some font that provides support for that script.  On Ubuntu, most of these packages are in packages starting with `fonts-`.  Google's Noto fonts can be a good choice here, since they have good coverage of many scripts.